# I want the latest date and price from the table which has multiple prices with different date on that ID in big query. here is my query below

Tags: google-bigquery

the issue I am facing is that I don't want to group by the price column. I want to group by only id so I can get the latest date and price. but big query is not allowing me to run this query without group by price.

here is my query:

SELECT id,
max(created date) as latest date,
price
FROM `table name`
group by id

Comment: If any of these answer helped you, you can upvote or accept the answer. This can help future users who are having the same issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a fix for you. It is not the cleanest but it works.

```
SELECT id, "created date" as "latest date", price 
FROM (SELECT id, 
FIRST_VALUE("created date") OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY "created date" DESC) as "created date", 
FIRST_VALUE("price") OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY "created date" DESC) as "price" 
FROM "table name")
GROUP BY id
```

I think this should also work

```
SELECT UNIQUE id, 
FIRST_VALUE("created date") OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY "created date" DESC) as "created date", 
FIRST_VALUE("price") OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY "created date" DESC) as "price" 
FROM "table name"
```

Answer (score 0):

Use below approach

```
select as value 
  array_agg(t order by created_date desc limit 1)[offset(0)] 
from your_table t
group by id
```

Comment: obviously missed `limit 1` which otherwise can lead to resource issue

Answer (score 0):

In this case, I used the aggregate function [ARRAY_AGG](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/aggregate_functions#array_agg), which returns an array ordered by date, and gets only one record per ID. Also,
I used the [OFFSET](https://roboquery.com/app/syntax-offset-and-ordinal-function-bigquery) command that reads the array from position zero.

```
WITH Example AS
(SELECT 1 as ID, 32.5 as price, PARSE_DATE("%x", "12/25/22")  as sdate UNION ALL
SELECT 1 as ID, 3 as price,  PARSE_DATE("%x",'01/13/22') as sdate UNION ALL
SELECT 2 as ID, 2.5 as price,  PARSE_DATE("%x",'01/30/22')  as sdate UNION ALL
SELECT 3 as ID, 5 as price,  PARSE_DATE("%x",'01/20/22')  as sdate UNION ALL
SELECT 4 as ID, 50 as price,  PARSE_DATE("%x",'01/10/22') as sdate UNION ALL
SELECT 4 as ID, 1.13 as price,  PARSE_DATE("%x",'01/08/22') as sdate UNION ALL
SELECT 5 as ID, 150 as price,  PARSE_DATE("%x",'01/05/22') as sdate UNION ALL
SELECT 6 as ID, 30 as price,  PARSE_DATE("%x",'01/05/22') as sdate UNION ALL
SELECT 7 as ID, 5.2 as price,  PARSE_DATE("%x",'01/03/22') as sdate UNION ALL
SELECT 8 as ID, 200 as price,  PARSE_DATE("%x",'02/01/22') as sdate
)
SELECT AS VALUE ARRAY_AGG(table ORDER BY sdate DESC LIMIT 1)[OFFSET(0)]
FROM Example table
group by id
```

[image]